# how to update/re-render a React list after an item is deleted, using classes

Tags: reactjs

Thanks for any support. I'm learning React and need to solve the problem consisting in that I can't make React to re-render after an item is deleted from a list.

Firstly I would like to say that I have follow the answers I found searching but still no luck.

The scenario is that I'm using React to fetch a list from and API and render it in the same screen with a form for editing and listing the specific information for every item in the list (fields are just name and lastname). The list is displayed with a button for edit which makes the form for edit, and with another button for delete. The list displays the two only fields which are name and lastname which are displayed using ListGroupItem from reacstrap that when onClick uses the form for listing only. I also have the logic for add items.

I'm able to add, update, list with no problems and re-rendering properly. However when deleting I'm just able to delete the item from the API but I have to manually re-render to display the update list

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { Button, Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";

import ListBebes from "./components/ListBebes";

import AddBebeForm from "./components/AddBebeForm";

import EditBebeForm from "./components/EditBebeForm";

import { fetchBebes, fetchBebe, addBebe, deleteBebe } from "./api";

import Websocket from "react-websocket";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bebes: [],
      bebe: {},
      current_bebe_id: 0,
      is_creating: true,
      is_fetching: true,
      is_justRead: true,
      has_updated: false,
    };
    this.socket = React.createRef();
    this.focusSocket = this.focusSocket.bind(this);
    this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this);
    this.handleEditClick = this.handleEditClick.bind(this);
    this.handleDeleteClick = this.handleDeleteClick.bind(this);
    this.handleAddBebe = this.handleAddBebe.bind(this);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    this.handleSaveBebe = this.handleSaveBebe.bind(this);
    this.handleOnNombresChange = this.handleOnNombresChange.bind(this);
    this.handleOnApellidosChange = this.handleOnApellidosChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.has_updated === true) {
      this.getData();
      this.setState({ has_updated: false });
    }
  }

  focusSocket() {
    this.socket.current.focus();
  }

  async getData() {
    let data = await fetchBebes();
    this.setState({ bebes: data, is_fetching: false });
  }

  async handleItemClick(id) {
    let selected_bebe = await fetchBebe(id);
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        is_creating: false,
        is_justRead: true,
        current_bebe_id: id,
        bebe: selected_bebe,
      };
    });
  }

  async handleEditClick(id) {
    let selected_bebe = await fetchBebe(id);

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        is_creating: false,
        is_justRead: false,
        current_bebe_id: id,
        bebe: selected_bebe,
      };
    });
  }

  async handleDeleteClick(id) {
    let antesBebes = [...this.state.bebes];
    console.log(antesBebes);
    let index = antesBebes.findIndex((i) => i.id === id);
    console.log(`the index es ${index} y el id es ${id}`);
    await deleteBebe(id);
    antesBebes.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(antesBebes);
    this.setState({ bebes: [...antesBebes], has_updated: true });
    //this.setState({ bebes: this.state.bebes, has_updated: true });
    //console.log(antesBebes);
    console.log("it was deleted...");
    //window.location.reload();
    //this.setState((prevState) => {
    //return {
    //bebes: antesBebes,
    //has_updated: true,
    //};
    //});
    //this.getData();
  }

  handleAddBebe() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { is_creating: true };
    });
  }

  async handleSaveBebe(data) {
    await addBebe(data);
    await this.getData();
  }

  handleData(data) {
    let result = JSON.parse(data);
    let current_bebe = this.state.bebe;
    if (current_bebe.id === result.id) {
      this.setState({ bebe: result });
    }
  }

  handleOnNombresChange(e) {
    let nombres = e.target.value;
    let current_bebe = this.state.bebe;
    current_bebe.nombres = nombres;

    this.setState({
      bebe: current_bebe,
      has_updated: true,
    });

    const socket = this.socket.current;
    socket.state.ws.send(JSON.stringify(current_bebe));
  }

  handleOnApellidosChange(e) {
    let apellidos = e.target.value;
    let current_bebe = this.state.bebe;
    current_bebe.apellidos = apellidos;

    this.setState({
      bebe: current_bebe,
      has_updated: true,
    });

    //const socket = this.refs.socket;
    const socket = this.socket.current;
    socket.state.ws.send(JSON.stringify(current_bebe));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col xs="10">
              <h2>Hello</h2>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleAddBebe}>
                Create a new note
              </Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col xs="4">
              {this.state.is_fetching ? (
                "Loading..."
              ) : (
                <ListBebes
                  bebes={this.state.bebes}
                  handleItemClick={(id) => this.handleItemClick(id)}
                  handleEditClick={(id) => this.handleEditClick(id)}
                  handleDeleteClick={(id) => this.handleDeleteClick(id)}
                ></ListBebes>
              )}
            </Col>
            <Col xs="8">
              {this.state.is_creating ? (
                <AddBebeForm handleSave={this.handleSaveBebe} />
              ) : (
                <EditBebeForm
                  handleNombresChange={this.handleOnNombresChange}
                  handleApellidosChange={this.handleOnApellidosChange}
                  bebe={this.state.bebe}
                  soloLeer={this.state.is_justRead}
                />
              )}
              <Websocket
                ref={this.socket}
                url="ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/bebes"
                onMessage={this.handleData.bind(this)}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You must not be removing the item from the list. If the item is removed then it will have to refresh because the data is no longer there.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(id);` at the beginning of `handleDelete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It happened that by placing code in the delete function handleDeleteClick() and also in componentDidUpdate I was messing things up.
The final code for delete is:

```
async handleDeleteClick(id) {
    let antesBebes = [...this.state.bebes];
    let index = antesBebes.findIndex((i) => i.id === id);
    await deleteBebe(id);
    antesBebes.splice(index, 1);
    await this.setState({ bebes: antesBebes });
  }
```

This code may have other problems but as far as the original goal was, this solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug the following lines? and print `[...antesBebes]` |  `this.state.bebes` and `antesBebes`  after line `3` ?

I have some suspension about these lines, Can't debug them though because you haven't added all your components in here.

```
1    antesBebes.splice(index, 1);
2    console.log(antesBebes);
3    this.setState({ bebes: [...antesBebes], has_updated: true });
```

My recommendation is to use one of the following to manage your state in react application:

1. React Hooks -- recommended for small application like yours [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)
2. React Redux -- [link](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: I did a print after the deletion in handleDeleteClick with console.log(antesBebes) and a console.log(this.state.bebes) and both are the same. I don't know if this is the feedback you need. Aboutthe line number 1 antesBebes.splice(index, 1) I wrote it to have the state reflecting the deletion performed with the api.js file wich as you mentioned I have not uploaded here yet.

Comment: hmmmm. Can you remove `componentDidMount` and call `this.getData();` inside `constructor()` please?  for your reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: I tried getting rid of the componentDidMount logic and calling this.getData() inside constructor with no luck. I will try to make it work with classes due unfortunately I followed some already predefined logic from a material tutorial I'm following. I agree though that with hooks could work faster. If someone has an idea on how to fix it with classes I'm ready, this is just for learning so I can take the time to understand.